# I don't believe boxShadow is being applied correctly on Code 2

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I don't believe box-Shadow is being applied correctly on **Code 2.** Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? And they both use Box Shadow.

This is weird cause if they are both applied in the same exact manner, what is causing the 2nd code to act differently? I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone figure this out for me?

**Code 1, and Code 2.**

https://jsfiddle.net/1xmkespg/5/

**Code 1:**

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/1xmkespg/10/

**Code 2:**

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/1xmkespg/12/

**Code 2:**

```html
<button id="playButton4" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px ); border: 3px solid #0059dd;"
onclick=" 
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton4');
    var player = document.getElementById('player4');
      document.querySelector('#playButton4 .initial').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton4 .pause').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton4 .play').style.display='none';
    player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
playButton4.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
    playButton4.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px';
    playButton4.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    playButton4.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 20px #e77d19';
    playButton4.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playButton4.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
    document.querySelector('#playButton4 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
    player.play();
    } else {
playButton4.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
    playButton4.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px';
playButton4.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 20px #e77d19';
    playButton4.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    playButton4.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playButton4.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
    document.querySelector('#playButton4 .play').style.display='inline-block';
    player.pause();
    }">

  <svg class="initial" width="90" height="108" viewbox="0 -3 85 120">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:black; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="pause" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewbox="0 0 16 14">
    <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z"
    fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="play" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewbox="0 0 16 14">
    <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.7623zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z" fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
  </svg>

</button>

<audio id="player4" style="display:none;">
  <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: To make your code a lot more readable, try using a `<script>` tag with your JavaScript in it, instead of these long strings in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Can you tell me why box shadow when applied to the 2nd Code looks differently than the first code? If they are both applied in the same exact way, using the same method?

Comment: It is extremely difficult to read your code. If you made it more readable you might be able to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not hiding the initial border style in code 2 once the onclick function is activated. You need to add:

```
playButton4.style.border='none';
```

This should remove the blue border.